# Hiding HTML javascript code inside a custom created button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I'm new to code and need some help. I'm running a online store and I'm using selz.com. A person can upload digital goods and imbed a 'buy now' button on their site provided by Selz. Now Selz button design is very ugly and I want to make a new button design but host all the code when clicking on the 'Buy now' button from Selz. Another important note, the code below is the Selz 'buy now' button that they provide. Once a person clicks on the button a overlay effect happens for a payout system. Here is a youtube like on what I'm talking about - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-Dvm17jYeo

Is this possible to create a custom button that stores all the data necessary to activate Selz 'buy now' button overlay effect?

Below is the code of the Selz 'buy now' button. Thank you for your time!!!

```
<script data-selz-t="_selz-btn-default" data-selz-a="modal" data-selz-ct="f2f2f2" data-selz-  cb="fd4f06" data-selz-b="http://selz.co/1triLby">
if (typeof _$elz === "undefined") { var _$elz = {}; }
if (typeof _$elz.b === "undefined") { 
_$elz.b = { e: document.createElement("script") }; 
_$elz.b.e.src = "https://selz.com/embed/button"; 
document.body.appendChild(_$elz.b.e); }
</script>
<a href="http://selz.co/1triLby" target="_blank" class="_selz_nojs_link">Buy this on Selz</a>
<a href="https://selz.com" target="_blank" class="_selz_nojs_link">Sell digital downloads on Selz</a>
```

Comment: Often part of using a third party tool like this is having to put up with their branding. E.g the ubiquitous PayPal button. You could use a tool like Firebug for Firefox, to inspect the script rendered button. If there is a clas applied to it, you may be able to overide the class, if it uses inline styles, your life just got harder.

Comment: Is there somewhere online I can go to fix this problem? It's getting way over my head...

Comment: Try contacting Selz delveloper support (or similar). They may be able to help you or point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, I tried this and they told me it was not possible but they will bring it to the attention of their managers and such...any other ideas? You have been a great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't like the regular Selz button, we have a jQuery plugin which I think is just what you need:
https://github.com/Selz/jquery.selz

It'll allow you to create your own button and with very little coding use the overlay and if you want, get callbacks when events take place within the overlay.

I'm not sure who here told you that you can't do it but I'll mention it to support that we should be pushing this more as it's a lot more flexible to users that have a bit of coding knowledge like yourself.

p.s. we're changing the design of the button to a more flat design shortly so it won't be "ugly" as you call it. Design is always subjective though so you're never going to please everyone :)

Cheers
Sam
- Designer and front end dev at Selz

Comment: That's great to hear! I'm pumped to see the new button design.  Sorry about the word "ugly"...Good news is I got it to work on my site and it looks great. I love the overlay effect. Selz is a great ecommerce solution. Maybe you can have a button design area at Selz so people can create their own? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! A custom button designer is definitely on our list of features to build (along with a lot of other stuff). I'd personally love to build something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test in your exact situation, but I was able to make an ugly button, then hide it.

My pretty button runs its own code, then runs the `click` event on the ugly button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Ugly Button Test</title>

        <style>
        .fugly {
        background-color: yellow;
        color: red;
        border: 4px dotted purple;
        }

        .pretty {
        background-color: blue;
        color: yellow;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="fixFugly()">

    <button class="fugly" data-my-unique-id="rbutton1">Hidden fugly button</button>

     <script>
     function fixFugly() {
       var uglyButton = document.querySelector('[data-my-unique-id="rbutton1"]');
       uglyButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
         alert("Ugly button pushed");
       });


       var prettyButton = document.createElement("button");
       prettyButton.className = "pretty";
       prettyButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Push me!"));
       uglyButton.parentNode.appendChild(prettyButton);

       uglyButton.style.display = "none";

       prettyButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
         alert("Pretty button pushed");

         var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
           'view': window,
           'bubbles': true,
           'cancelable': true
         });
         uglyButton.dispatchEvent(event);        
       });

     }
     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is so close to what I'm trying to do. Where would you put the code I provided in my original message? Thanks again!

Comment: @MoonEchoAudio Because I can't reproduce your situation, I can't answer that.  Anything I say would just be guesswork.

Comment: I see, thanks for all your hard work. I got a step closer with your code!